# Bitonic sort, mpi4py

Tags: python, sorting, parallel-processing, mpi

I am attempting to implement the Bitonic-Sort algorithm.

```
Parallel Bitonic Sort Algorithm for processor Pk (for k := 0 : : : P  1)
d:= log P /* cube dimension */
sort(local  datak) /* sequential sort */
/* Bitonic Sort follows */
for i:=1 to d do
    window-id = Most Signicant (d-i) bits of Pk
    for j:=(i-1) down to 0 do
        if((window-id is even AND jth bit of Pk = 0) OR 
                   (window-id is odd AND jth bit of Pk = 1))
        then call CompareLow(j)
        else call CompareHigh(j)
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Source: http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~venugopa/parallel_summer2012/mpi_bitonic.html#expl

Unfortunately the descriptions of CompareHigh and CompareLow are shaky at best.

From my understanding, CompareHigh will take the data from the calling process, and its partner process, merge the two, sorted, and store the upper half in the calling process' data. CompareLow will do the same, and take the lower half.

I've verified that my implementation is selecting the correct partners and calling the correct CompareHigh/Low method during each iteration for each process, but my output is still only partially sorted. I'm assuming that my implementation of CompareHigh/Low is incorrect.

Here is a sample of my current output:

```
[0] [17 24 30 37]
[1] [ 92 114 147 212]
[2] [ 12  89  92 102]
[3] [172 185 202 248]
[4] [ 30  51 111 148]
[5] [148 149 158 172]
[6] [ 17  24  59 149]
[7] [160 230 247 250]
```

And here are my CompareHigh, CompareLow, and merge functions:

```
def CompareHigh(self, j):
    partner = self.getPartner(self.rank, j)
    print "[%d] initiating HIGH with %d" % (self.rank, partner)
    new_data = np.empty(self.data.shape, dtype='i')

    self.comm.Send(self.data, dest = partner, tag=55)
    self.comm.Recv(new_data, source = partner, tag=55)

    assert(self.data.shape == new_data.shape)
    self.data = np.split(self.merge(data, new_data), 2)[1]

def CompareLow(self, j):
    partner = self.getPartner(self.rank, j)
    print "[%d] initiating LOW with %d" % (self.rank, partner)
    new_data = np.empty(self.data.shape, dtype='i')

    self.comm.Recv(new_data, source = partner, tag=55)
    self.comm.Send(self.data, dest = partner, tag=55)

    assert(self.data.shape == new_data.shape)
    self.data = np.split(self.merge(data, new_data), 2)[0]

def merge(self, a, b):
    merged = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < a.shape[0] and j < b.shape[0]:
        if a[i] < b[j]:
            merged.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            merged.append(b[j])
            j += 1
    while i < a.shape[0]:
        merged.append(a[i])
        i += 1

    while j < a.shape[0]:
        merged.append(b[j])
        j += 1

    return np.array(merged)


def getPartner(self, rank, j):
    # Partner process is process with j_th bit of rank flipped
    j_mask = 1 << j
    partner = rank ^ j_mask
    return partner
```

Finally, here the actual algorithm loop:

```
# Generating map of bit_j for each process.
bit_j = [0 for i in range(d)]
for i in range(d):
    bit_j[i] = (rank >> i) & 1    

bs = BitonicSorter(data)
for i in range(1, d+1):

    window_id = rank >> i
    for j in reversed(range(0, i)):
        if rank == 0: print "[%d] iteration %d, %d" %(rank, i, j) 
        comm.Barrier()
        if (window_id%2 == 0 and bit_j[j] == 0) \
                    or (window_id%2 == 1 and bit_j[j] == 1):
            bs.CompareLow(j)
        else:
            bs.CompareHigh(j)
        if rank == 0: print ""
        comm.Barrier()

if rank != 0:
    comm.Send(bs.data, dest = 0, tag=55)
    comm.Barrier()

else:
    dataset[0] = bs.data
    for i in range(1, size) :
        comm.Recv(dataset[i], source = i, tag=55)
    comm.Barrier()
    for i, datai in enumerate(dataset):
        print "[%d]\t%s" % (i, str(datai))
    dataset = np.array(dataset).reshape(data_size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well bugger me:

```
self.data = np.split(self.merge(data, new_data), 2)
```

Were the problematic lines. I'm not sure what variable data was bound to, but that was the problem right there.